# Adding Title to ggplot from the dataset itself

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I am working with the R programming language. I made the following graph using the built-in "mtcars" dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
a = ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("mtcars: wt vs mpg")
```

[image]

**Question:** Now, I am trying to customize the title, but I want the title to "contain a variable reference", for example:

```
b = ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("mtcars: wt vs mpg - average mpg = mean(mtcars$mpg)")
```

But this command literally just prints the code I wrote:

[image]

I know that the "mean" command runs by itself:

```
 mean(mtcars$mpg)
[1] 20.09062
```

But can someone please help me change this code:

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("mtcars: wt vs mpg - average mpg = mean(mtcars$mpg)")
```

So that it produces something like this (note: here, I manually wrote the "mean" by hand):

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `paste()`.

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() + ggtitle(paste0("mtcars: wt vs mpg - average mpg = ", mean(mtcars$mpg)))
```

If you need to you can add more text and variables with commas like so:

```
ggtitle(paste0('text ', var1, 'text2 etc ', var2, var3, 'text3'))
```

Note that `paste0` is a variant of `paste` that concatenates things with no space or separator in between.

Comment: @ Elle :Thank you so much for your answer! I tried this and it works! Up until now, I have been writing all titles manually. I can't wait to automatically do this using the way you showed me! Thank you so much!

Comment: @ Elle : After 6 minutes, I will be able to formally accept your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 3):

An option with `glue`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(glue)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
      geom_point() + 
      ggtitle(glue("mtcars: wt vs mpg - average mpg = {mean(mtcars$mpg)}"))
```

Answer (score 2):

We could also use `str_c` from `stringr` package which is part of `tidyverse` package. `str_c` is equivalent to `paste0`

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() + ggtitle(str_c("mtcars: wt vs mpg - average mpg = ", mean(mtcars$mpg)))
```